# Time dilation between objects

Tags: time-dilation

Imagine three clocks. One very heavy clock (call it the "sun clock"). Another clock is orbiting the "sun clock" and is as massive as the earth. The third clock is orbiting the "earth clock" and is as massive as the moon.

All of these objects have a mass, velocity and acceleration (due to gravity). For simplification we can define the size (if relevant) of the objects to be 0. Feel free to make other simplifications if you want.

How do I calculate the "velocity of time" between 0 and 1 (or probably between 0 and c) where 1 is an object completely unaffected by gravity.

Comment: The mass of the clock is irrelevant. Time dilation occurs as a result of spacetime distortion. The relative strength of the gravitational field in which the clocks sit is of importance and the relative motion of the two clocks is of importance. Stronger gravitational fields mean time ticks slower (relative a clock in a weaker gravitational field). The fact you define 3 clocks in your system is irrelevant, there are no absolute reference frames and as such, it only makes sense to talk about the relative difference in clock speed between pairs of clocks. Not an answer, just some things to note.

Comment: What you're looking for is general relativity and the equations for calculating relative clock speeds are - in general - non trivial.

Comment: @JeneralJames It seems plausible to me that it should be possible to derive a fairly simple formula that takes the mass and distance and gives a factor for relative clock speed. One acceptable simplification would be that relative velocity is 0 (negligible). The mass of the clock is what defines the magnitude of curvature in my question.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to calculate relative clock velocity as a function of force?